# Difference between 佔 and 占

Tags: meaning, usage

In this post, I am discussing characters in traditional writing.

When reading as zhan4, I wonder what the difference between 佔 and 占 is. Is there a division in use by meaning? Or, is one totally preferred over the other?

Comment: 佔 is not used in simplified Chinese.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When reading as **zhàn**, the word meaning *to occupy/seize* has historically been written with both [「佔」](https://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/variants/rbt/word_attribute.rbt?quote_code=QTAwMTE5) and [「占」](https://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/variants/rbt/word_attribute.rbt?quote_code=QTAwNDQ2).

The following may give an indication of the preferences of the spellings in various Traditional-Character-using areas, based on how publicly-available dictionaries record vocabulary:

- Taiwan: Records primary entries under 「占」, and lists 「佔」 as a variant; see e.g. [《教育部國語辭典簡編本》占領](https://dict.concised.moe.edu.tw/dictView.jsp?ID=29847&q=1)
- Hong Kong: Records primary entries under 「佔」, and lists 「占」 as a variant; see e.g. [《粵語審音配詞字庫》](https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk//Lexis/lexi-can/):

  > 佔：佔據, 霸佔, 佔盡先機，佔便宜, 佔領, 佔地, 佔有, 侵佔
  > 占：同「佔」字

  or [《粵典》佔](https://words.hk/zidin/wan/?q=%E4%BD%94)
- South Korea (bonus): Records entries under 「占」; see e.g. [Naver 辭典: 占領](https://hanja.dict.naver.com/#/entry/ccko/42710b9fce0c4b2a8e8f9499541c5a49)

Comment: I just want to add, I checked my hongkong published dictionary and it listed both as equally acceptable (佔優勢。∥也作「占」。)  Perhaps it is part of the modern internet, but I do think alternate official characters are intermingling a lot in the current day （＾_＾）

Comment: @zagrycha In this answer, I made sure to mention what the primary entry (the entry where the full definition is given) was. If your dictionary is a 詞典 (not 字典), you can check as well.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, and to be clear I am not at all disagreeing with your main post.  Yes it is a 詞典, and this dictionary usually does not list alternate characters at all, unless it considers them equally accptable to use-- things that are just considered general 異體字 get no mention in that dictionary at all-- not a  or 盐 to be seen even though I see both in hk, they aren't recognized enough.  Anyway it was just an anecdotal note I thought was interesting of things mixing （＾_＾）

Answer (score 0):

[占](https://cantoneseplus.com/character/1961)  /zhan1/

> divine; practise divination.

> to divine

> As in [占卜](https://cantoneseplus.com/word/14339)

[佔](https://cantoneseplus.com/character/850) /zhan4/

> occupy; seize; take possession of

> As in [佔領](https://cantoneseplus.com/word/8805)

"Occupy" and "seize" are human activities, therefore, it has radical: 亻 (human)

The two characters are only related by having similar phonetics since 占 is the phonetic component of 佔

Notice: 占 is also used as the simplified character of 佔, Therefore, 佔領 in simplified Chinese would be 占領, and it is read as  /zhan4 ling3/ not 占領 /zhan1 ling3/